# How to create a table and put each array item into a <td> using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a table exclusively in jQuery.

```
$(function() {

    var genres = ["Genre1", "Genre2", "Genre3", "Genre4", "Genre5", "Romance", "Satire"];
    console.log(genres);
}
```

I was able to make a list using this code.

```
for (var i = 0; i < genres.length; i++) {
    console.log(genres[i]);
    $('ul').append("<li>" + genres[i] + "</li>")
}
```

I am trying to make a table that includes the genres. This is the code I am using - but it is not working, and I don't know why.

```
for (var i = 0; i < genres.length; i++) {
    console.log(genres[i]);
    $('ul').append("<tr><td>" + genres[i] + "</td></tr>")
}

$('td').each(genres, function(index, value) {});
```

EDIT: This is my entire JS code

```
$(function() {

    var genres = ["Fiction", "Comedy", "Drama", "Horror", "Non-fiction", "Romance", "Satire"];
    console.log(genres);

    for (var i = 0; i < genres.length; i++) {
        console.log(genres[i]);
        $('ul').append("<li>"+genres[i]+"</li>")
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < genres.length; i++) {
        console.log(genres[i]);
        $('td').append("<tr><td>"+genres[i]+"</td></tr>")
    }

    $('td').each(genres, function(index, value) {
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <ul> </ul>
    <td> </td>
</body>
```

Link to a picture of the results of my code. I want the duplicate row to be into a table instead of a list.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbiCo.jpg

Comment: Your code seems to be incomplete... Can you rephrase?

Comment: I think it should be $('td').append( .... 
instead of $('ul').append( ....
in the table code.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I just looked at the question that this is supposed to be an exact duplicate of and it's not a duplicate.  The linked question asks how to iterate over `td` elements but this is asking how to generate them.  You might want to re-consider whether or not this is a duplicate.

Comment: @greyseal96 Do you feel I should reopen it?

Comment: @PraveenKumar In my opinion, yes. The code given from OP attempts to use the jQuery each function above and even though it is incomplete and I don't think that it's necessary to use it for what OP is trying to do, as I understand the question, this is a different question than the one linked. I think that OP needs to make some edits to help the rest of us be able to answer the questions but I don't think that it is a duplicate. That's just my opinion. If you reopen the question, I'll suggest the edits in a comment and maybe OP can get a helpful answer.

Comment: @Radu I tried changing it to td and it didnt work. Thanks for the response though, any other ideas ?

Comment: @dol226 Can you edit your question to show what html you've got and, if you're getting any errors, what they are?  Right now, we can only see part of what you've got.  Also, in your last code block above, you've got an empty `each` block.  Did you mean for that to be empty or is something missing from there?

Comment: @greyseal96 Done...

Comment: Genres should be columns or rows in the table?
Now, it looks like you have a lot of rows with only one cell

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thank you, sir, for reopening the question!  Hopefully the OP makes the edits and cleans up the question a little bit to fix it.

Comment: Um, that _is_ a table. If you want all the entries to be in one row, use only a single `tr`.

Comment: @dol226 please tell me if my answer is  what you wanted in Romania is 3:34 AM :) :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying append table rows `tr` and columns `td` to a `ul` which, even if it works (I don't think that it will), will not be correct html.  You should only append `tr` and `td` to a `table` so  you'll need to add that element to your HTML.  So your HTML should look like this:

```
<body>
    <ul></ul>
    <table></table>
</body>
```

And your jQuery code would look like something like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < genres.length; i++) {
    $('ul').append("<li>" + genres[i] + "</li>");
    $('table').append("<tr><td>" + genres[i] + "</td></tr>");
}
```

Take a look at [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6p9regoh/) to see a more complete example.

Answer (score 0):

Your `td` should be a `table`. Putting a `tr` in anything other than a `table` (if it has no `tbody`), `thead`, `tbody`, or `tfoot` is invalid HTML.

I'm not sure what you mean by "I want the duplicate row to be into a table instead of a list". The second element in your screenshot *is* a table. If you want all your genres in a single row, put all of the `td`s into a single `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want? :)

html:

```
  <body>
    <ul></ul>
    <table> </table>
  </body>
```

and jquery:

```
 var genres = ["Genre1", "Genre2", "Genre3", "Genre4", "Genre5", "Romance", "Satire"];

for (var i = 0; i < genres.length; i++) {
  console.log(genres[i]);
  $('ul').append('<li>'+ genres[i] +'</li>');
};
    $('table').append("<tr>")
    for (var i = 0; i < genres.length; i++) {
      console.log(genres[i]);
      $('table').append("<td>" + genres[i] + "</td>")
    }
    $('table').append("</tr>")
```

You can see the result here: https://codepen.io/radu_cruceana/pen/eeWNYj

Comment: @dol226  did you check my answer?